# How to check if an <option> from a <select> tag is selected in expression engine?

Tags: select, html-select, expressionengine

I asked this over at Expression Engine Answer but was directed here. I would like to show a snippet of code only if a certain option is selected in a tag. This is what I have but it does not work.

```
<select id="size" name="size" value="">
   <option value="one">one</option>
   <option value="two">two</option>
</select>

{if size.value == "two"}
   //code I want to show
{/if}
```

Comment: The if-code should be executed after the value is set. Is this the complete code?

Comment: If there a way to do it before the form that this select is in is submitted? So just when that option is clicked on in the select?